# get the count of an occurence of expression in a field in mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have a field in mysql table named "category". Inside them , i stored values like "main/item1/000" and it is filled from "item1" till "itemN" with the fixed "main" . ( Using javascript , i would like to implement this )

**1 )**  What i am looking for is to get the count of each item, like the count of the "item1" or "item2" etc.. I have searched and didnt get the results. Regexpression is what i think is the way to solve this.

My logic says this : ( its an error i know )

```
SELECT COUNT(category) from myTable WHERE "main/"varaiable_here = "item1"
```

**2 )**  how to get the "item1" from the "/" seperated string

Comment: @A.Wolff - i think  ajax is needed? can u help on the main matter

Comment: Look at the MySQL function `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find count of item2 in category in your table use:

```
 SELECT count(*) 
 FROM mytable 
 WHERE category LIKE '%item2%';
```

To find string between two "/" you could use:

```
SELECT substring_index(substring_index(category,'/',-2),'/',1) 
FROM mytable;
```

[Here's](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43dcf7/3) the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks @almas shaikh . it really worked. Also, cant we merge both and use like this:   `SELECT COUNT(substring_index(substring_index(category,'/',-2),'/',1) )
FROM mytable;`

Comment: Above query of yours will give you number of rows you have in your table and you will end up complicating your query. What exactly you mean when you say merge both? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: sorry, a small mistake, though very complex, this is what i expected.. ( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7e9d/1 ) ..... `SELECT COUNT(substring_index(substring_index(var,'/',-2),'/',1) ) FROM mytable WHERE  substring_index(substring_index(var,'/',-2),'/',1) ="tem2"; `

Comment: Just use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE substring_index(substring_index(var,'/',-2),'/',1) ="tem2";`

Comment: when i implemented i am getting this error. when i did like this : `foreach ($result as $record) { 
$ww = db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items WHERE substring_index(substring_index(items.odec,'/',-2),'/',1) ='".$selValue."'");
}

$w = $ww;
echo $w;`

Comment: The error is  `Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DatabaseStatementBase could not be converted to string in getCount()`